# Why is the header badge count pink?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This has been bothering me for [more than two years now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWZVL.png), and I've always wondered: why in the world is the top badge count color pink (or more specifically, `#FFDBDB`)?

[image]

Wouldn't white be better? No?

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that it is white on meta. I had noticed this before, but have no issues with pink.

Comment: CANNOT UNSEE ***:(***

Comment: oh man, that took me two minutes to see, but Strix is right -- you really can't unsee it.

Comment: I think it's a way to deemphasise the badge count without resorting to grey or transparency

Comment: @badp it makes them sound out more to me...maybe not when scanning, but once you see it...

Comment: I noticed this, but never thought enough about it to ask anyone..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have no idea why it's been pink... Looking at my original design mockup for the site back when it was gaming.se it wasn't pink.

Anyway, I un-pinked it. The change will be in the next prod build.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, any idea when that'll be?

Comment: It appears to be unpinked as of now.

Comment: @MBraedley next build tends to mean next day